# Convert Char into a String

Tags: scala

Given `s : String` how can I cast the result of

```
s.first()
```

into a `String` ?

Comment: The title of the question is poorly chosen. It is flatly impossible to _cast_ a `Char` to a `String`. It must be _converted_ to a `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String doesn't have a `.first()` function.  Do you mean `.head`?

Using `head` and returning a String is as simple as:

```
s.head.toString
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was relying on the eclipse autocomplete which suggested me the method: `first: Char - scala.collection.IterableLike`.

Comment: Similarly, `s.charAt(0).toString`. This avoids the implicit conversion of `String` to a `StringOps` so things like `head` may be used.

Comment: You could also use s.substring(0,1) which will give you a string directly.

Comment: I prefer `head` but by the way `s(0).toString` would also work, or even shorter but completely unreadable `s"${s(0)}"`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the method `take` as followed:

```
scala> val s = "abcdef"
s: String = abcdef

scala> val first = s.take(1)
first: String = a

scala>
```

Comment: This has the nice property of not dying on empty strings: `"".take(1) == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
val s : String = "hello"
val first : String = s(0)+""
```